# Appropriate values for fluid-structure interaction model using finite element method in MATLAB

Tags: finite-element, matlab

I'm having a program to compute the solution for a fluid-structure interaction model (blood and blood vessel walls) using FEM in MATLAB. The program is running fine but the function that I'm representing doesn't look too well. The differences between the values are too big and the function looks quite spiky.
[image: Spiky function]

Here are the values that I used:

```
a=0;
b=4;
c=0;
d=6;
g=1; %thickness of structure layer
dxs=0.2; %step for structure
dxf=0.25; %step for fluid
dy=0.5; %step on y axis
NNAB=(2*g)/dxs+(b-a-2*g)/dxf-1; %no of points on x-axis
NNAD=(d-c)/dy+1; %no of points on y-axis
NTN=NNAD*NNAB; %total no of points

Lc=0.65; %characteristic length
vc=0.3; %characteristic velocity
Tc=300; %characteristic temperature
T0=1.5; %initial temperature
alphaf=303*Tc; %thermal expansion in fluid
alphas=100*Tc; %thermal expansion in structure
kf=0.52; %thermal conductivity in fluid
ks=0.46; %thermal conductivity in structure
mu=0.0035; %dynamic viscosity
cf=3617; %specific heat in fluid
cs=3306;
rhos=1160; %structure density
rho0=1060; %fluid density at temp T0
g2=9.81*(Lc/(vc^2)); %dimensionless
E=80000; %Young's modulus for rubber
sigma=0.46; %Poisson's coefficient for rubber %0.32, 0.36, 0.41, 0.49
nu=E/(2+2*sigma);
lambda=(E*sigma)/((1+sigma)*(1-2*sigma)); %Lame coefficients
k1=((3*lambda+2*nu)/3)/(rhos*(vc^2)); %compression modulus
tau=150*(vc/Lc); %constant which gives the time interval
N=4000; %divides the time interval
epsilon=0.4; %viscoelastic parameter, must be <1
fs1=2*(Lc/(rhos*(vc^2)))*(10^2); %dimensionless force
fs2=(Lc/(rhos*(vc^2)))*0; %dimensionless

Re=(rho0*vc*Lc)/mu; 
Prf=(mu*cf)/kf; %fluid Prandtl no
Prs=((mu*cs)/ks)*(rhos/rho0);
Ec=(vc^2)/(cs*Tc);
```

All the variables that I'm working with are dimensionless. Is there a way to make it look better like functions in 3D look like? I keep on thinking the values are not chosen right. I'm aiming for something like this [3D MATLAB function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/creating-3-d-plots.html):

Here are also the matrix coefficients (the colored terms are most of the time the steps used depending on the domain that the integral is calculated.)

[image: Matrix coefficients]

Can this be done in MATLAB or should I search for a different software? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. Are you asking what values the physical constants should have? Or what the test case should be? Separately, you say that the program is "working fine", but have you verified that it is *correct*?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I have double checked the entries of the matrix, the right-hand side term and everything seems just right. This is why I think the choice of the values of the physical constants is decisive.

Comment: I also don't understand these strange assumptions. You have verified that the your matrices are correct (questionable proof, how you would ever confirm this for something this complex?), but you somehow still question if your parameters are correct? Either you had bugs in your code, your solver isn't correct, or the problem is unstable, or maybe you didn't interpret the solution correctly and just wrote some completely incorrect plotting code. Of course MATLAB (and all other turing complete languages) can do anything.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Because there's a whole theory behind writing that matrix, this is why I'm pretty sure the matrix is written correct. I've just inverted the matrix and multiplied with the right-hand side term. Changing one parameter changed the outcome of the figure significantly, this is why I keep thinking I might not have chosen the parameters right.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman But yes, the problem is unsteady. Is this a cause?

Comment: Maybe. You haven't shared any such details, so noone has any idea what you are even solving here or whether any of the code at any part is correct.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I'm using Uzawa's algorithm to determine the solution but I want to only represent the velocity in the fluid. Because it's an iterative method, at the next step I'm representing also the pressure, so the right-hand side term will have also the pressure at the previous step.

Comment: The problem is too complicated to say for sure what the issue is. Set all coupling parameters to zero so that you end up with a number of independent problems. Then verify correctness of these independent problems via the Method of Manufactured Solutions. If you're convinced that the solutions are correct, re-introduce the coupling parameters one by one.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I can't do that. The problem that I'm solving is a coupled one.

Comment: @AgentOrange Then you haven't read my comment carefully.